# How to get all questions which have an answer by a specified user and with no accepted answer?

Tags: t-sql, dataexplorer

I want to create a query in SE Data Explorer which does the follows:

> Get all questions which have (at least) an answer by a specified user and with no accepted answer (by anyone).

I have never written such code and the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) is lacking. Here is the line I mustered from examples and the slight documentation there is:

```
SELECT a.id AS [Post Link] FROM Posts a WHERE a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId## and PostTypeId = 2
```

This `Gets all questions which have (at least?) an answer by a specified user`, but I can't manage to filter only those with no accepted answer.

The type `Posts` has `AcceptedAnswerId int`, but no matter what `int` I put, I get nothing back. I couldn't even find what this property means or what values are legitimate. For `PostTypeId` I just tried and found that `1` is questions and `2` is answers.

I have also looked at the type [Type question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) and found `accepted_answer_id` with no documentation as to what it is. Moreover, I don't understand how to use these question types (using `FROM Questions` gives an error) or if these the right way to go. I do know I retrieve them by calling one of of the "Methods That Return This Type".

Lastly, I wonder if what I wrote is even a correct approach. Is the order in which filters are applied matter or do they apply simultaneously? What is the "best practice" way of doing the call I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you only look at the posts of a user. But you need to get the `AcceptedAnswerId` field of the corresponding question. This field qoul be `null` if the question has no accepted answer until now. I edited your query by adding a `JOIN` on the Posts table to get the question and the questions' `AcceptedAnswerId` field.

```
SELECT q.Id as [Post Link]
  FROM Posts a
    JOIN Posts q on a.ParentId = q.Id
  WHERE a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
    and a.PostTypeId = 2
    and q.AcceptedAnswerId is null
```

At this point you could also exclude closed questions by adding `and ClosedDate is null`

You can also find and try my solution [at the dataexplorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/195056/get-all-questions-which-have-at-least-an-answer-by-a-specified-user-and-with-no?UserId=3346612).

Comment: How do you know that `AcceptedAnswerId is null`? Where did you read that in the documentation?

Comment: I could not find this information within the documentation. But what else should be in this field, if there is no AcceptedAnswer? Further I've seen it in other queries and also used in my own ones.

Comment: I agree, I asked in case I'm missing some documentation. Other fields might not be so intuitive. I actually tried `AcceptedAnswerId = null` not knowing the syntax well.